# Chatter feed tracking for new record creation

Tags: trigger, rest-api, chatter, chatter-feed-tracking

I want to notify users  through chatter Stream  when a new record is created on an object
So when a new account record is created , a post at chatter will be notified to all or select users.

User should be notified of a new record creation only, without following objects and records hence being inundated with chatter noise. I am aware of chatter feed, however clearly this isn't sufficient.

Is this possible, or would an apex trigger be required.

Much thanks to all, would be grateful for anyone to elaborate if this is possible with workarounds.

Comment: I hate to pimp hence not putting this as an answer, but we're about to release an update ChattoMate that would allow you to do this quite easily, controlling which users get the notifications etc..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the Help page for Customizing Chatter Feed Tracking:

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_feed_tracking.htm

Like you said, the out-of-the-box Chatter might not have sufficient capabilities to do what you're asking, and their are more complex alternatives.  First, I believe you can create a `Trigger` on the appropriate `Chatter Objects`.  That would give you the greatest control over `Chatter Feed records` generation.  In the `Trigger`, you could evaluate who the User is and do different actions based on the `User` and the record itself (like create new appropiate `Chatter Feed Records`).

However, if that doesn't work, there is another alternative of using `Streaming API`.  It's kind of nifty: first you set up Queries (`PushTopic`).  The code then performs the `PushTopic` query at regular intervals (near-continuous or in a `trigger`-fashion) and it detects when a new record is created (or edited depending on your settings).  The `Streaming API` then sends a message to the `client` when it detects a change.  The client can then do whatever they want with it (like create a Chatter Feed Record).

I believe `Streaming API` is more for the use-case of a 3rd-party application or like you would use `Salesforce SOAP API` with Javascript on a page.

Streaming API docs:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_streaming/

Answer (score 1):

A potential workaround:

1. Create a field, perhaps called `this record` and give it two picklist values: `not created` and `created`
2. Write a workflow rule to run on creation and modify `this_record__c`, setting it equal to `created` (make sure the default is set to `not created`)
3. Turn on Chatter Feed Tracking for `this_record__c`

The resulting chatter post would read something to the effect of:

> user2878773 changed this record from not created to created

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need  trigger for that. Maybe you could create a group called New Records and users who want to see that a new record has been created could be a member of that group. You could then have a trigger on the objects you want to track make a post into the New Records group so everyone is notified.